# I have some questions about Firewall

Tags: networking, security, firewall

So I am pretty new to Linux (With the exception of Android), and being use to the old ways of Windows pretty much all I had to do for Firewall was turn it on and forget about it. However with Ubuntu Linux I see it is a bit more complicated than that. I am as of currently using GUFW for Firewall, it is set to allow outgoing and to deny ingoing. I was just wondering  if this might affect any of my programs ie. Skype...etc. from working properly? I am really new to all this and would love to learn more. Help is appreciated. I know you can set rules and what not, but I don't want to set rules for programs if it is not necessary. Just really confused....

Comment: I do not anticipate any problem. If, however, you have a problem, ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine using the firewall as is. The only time you should have to add a rule or exception is when you are hosting a resource from your machine such as a web site or an FTP server or some other resource that requires clients to connect to you. In this case you are a client (skype) connecting to a remote resource (Microsoft). The profiles used in GUFW are set to allow all outgoing traffic from your PC my default so this should not interfere with any of your Applications.

Comment: Okay awesome this is just what I wanted to hear! Now lets say I wanted to do file sharing within my home network, would I then have to set up a rule? I would assume so.

Comment: Yes samba will need to be added as an exception to allow traffic

Comment: Awesome, I guess the Uncomplicated Firewall is not all that complicated after all. I think it was mainly due to my OCD. I like to make sure everything works properly with certainty.

Comment: Yeah I was the same way when I started using ubuntu lol but good for you for going out and seeking the knowledge to make your system even more secure. I'm not sure what kind of PC you have (Desktop or laptop) as a recommendation for laptop users you can create profiles where you can make one for home with all the open ports you want and then have another so if you go to a coffee shop or something you can switch to this more secure profile to lock down you PC and have it to reject any and all traffic not initiated from your PC.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the profile options up top. It gave me the options of Home, Public, and Office I believe. I have what I like a "Desktop Replacement" Don't really take it around with me a lot since it is a 17in laptop. However I will be going on vacation soon. So when I connect to a public network I just would switch it to public on the profile selection thingy up top right?

Comment: Yeah just set it to Public and you'll be good to go